# What is the use of trackingFeature property in aem cq_dialog?

Tags: aem, aem-6

While anlalysing some aem component, I saw

```
trackingFeature="core-components:image:v2"
```

property in cq_dialog > .context.xml.  What is the use of ***trackingFeature="core-components:image:v2"*** ?

Answer (score 0):

This was [added across AEM Core Components](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/commit/699aacd7b1dc2b64553ee25b706b3f2cd3ae25a0) a couple of years back. The purpose of the change was to align the components with Coral UI tracking functionality. See [the Coral UI 3 docs](https://developer.adobe.com/experience-manager/reference-materials/6-5/coral-ui/coralui3/Coral.Dialog.html#Coral.Dialog:trackingFeature) for more information.

Judging by the comments on a [related GitHub issue](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/issues/477), Adobe use this API to provide some analytics as part of the [opt-in aggregated usage statistics](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-64/deploying/deploying/opt-in-aggregated-usage-statistics.html?lang=en)

Quoting from the docs:

> You can help improve Adobe Marketing Cloud by sending Adobe statistics about how you interact with AEM. This information does not contain any data about your company’s site visitors and will only be used to help Adobe deliver, support and improve your user experience.
>
> You can opt into usage statistics collection by using either the Touch UI or the Web Console.

It's likely that the component you're looking at is a [proxy component](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-core-components/using/developing/guidelines.html?lang=en#proxy-component-pattern) that extends one of the Core Components.